# Stream video frame Android-to-android

Tags: android, opencv, streaming

I currently work on an app where I use the phone camera and open CV to process the frames. Now I thought it would be cool to be able to send the frames to another Android client. I thought frame by frame with steamer could work, but don't know how to setup the host and if it's not efficient. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send each frame as a raw set of data you can use sockets.

This code below is old now but it worked fine when last tested - it sends an entire video but you can use the same to send whatever file you want:

```js
//Send the video file to helper over a Socket connection so he helper can compress the video file 
        Socket helperSocket = null;

        try {
            Log.d("VideoChunkDistributeTask doInBackground","connecting to: " + helperIPAddress + ":" + helperPort);
            helperSocket = new Socket(helperIPAddress, helperPort);
            BufferedOutputStream helperSocketBOS = new BufferedOutputStream(helperSocket.getOutputStream());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            //Write the video chunk to the output stream
            //Open the file
            File videoChunkFile = new File(videoChunkFileName);
            BufferedInputStream chunkFileIS = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(videoChunkFile));

            //First send a long with the file length - wrap the BufferedOutputStream  in a DataOuputStream to
            //allow us send a long directly
            DataOutputStream helperSocketDOS = new DataOutputStream(
                     new BufferedOutputStream(helperSocket.getOutputStream()));
            long chunkLength = videoChunkFile.length();
            helperSocketDOS.writeLong(chunkLength);
            Log.d("VideoChunkDistributeTask doInBackground","chunkLength: " + chunkLength);

            //Now loop through the video chunk file sending it to the helper via the socket - note this will simply 
            //do nothing if the file is empty
            int readCount = 0;
            int totalReadCount = 0;
            while(totalReadCount < chunkLength) {
                //write the buffer to the output stream of the socket
                readCount = chunkFileIS.read(buffer);
                helperSocketDOS.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                totalReadCount += readCount;
            }

            Log.d("VideoChunkDistributeTask doInBackground","file sent");
            chunkFileIS.close();
            helperSocketDOS.flush();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d("VideoChunkDistributeTask doInBackground","unknown host");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("VideoChunkDistributeTask doInBackground","IO exceptiont");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

The full source code is at: https://github.com/mickod/ColabAndroid/tree/master/src/com/amodtech/colabandroid

You may also find there are more up to date socket libraries available which might be better for you to use, but the general principles should be similar.

If you want to stream your video so that the other app can play it like a regular video it streams from the web, then you would want to set up a web server on the 'sending' device. At this point it might be easier to send it to a server and stream from there instead.